# Firebase not always getting all children from snapshot

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an app on Firebase. When I manually reload the database by calling `configureDatabase()` for example in my `viewDidLoad` everything works fine. However, when the system refreshes itself some of the children are missing in the data snapshot. Perhaps I have to configure something to get all children?

**Code**

```
func configureDatabase() {
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    // Listen for new messages in the Firebase database
    _refHandle = self.ref.child(username).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

        print(snapshot)
        self.messages.append(snapshot)
        self.tbl.reloadData()

    })
}
```

**When `configureDatabase()` is called**

> Snap (Group1) {
>       members = "[\"\Ud83d\Udc9c\": \"user1\", \"\Ud83c\Udf40\": \"user2\"]";
>       myScore = 0;
>       owner = user2; }

**When it refreshes by itself**

> Snap (Group1) {
>       myScore = 0; }

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I was using the `.ChildAdded` trigger but populating the child with children sequentially instead of all at once, so the method was called only the for the first addition, not the others.